# How to resolve "Could not find method bundle() for arguments [build_6plat21h.....] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension"?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Alright I submit, I am trying to get a Unity 3D project working in a View on Android and it seems easy enough thanks to some tutorials online. However, I am stuck at the part where I need to convert the unity project to a module/AAR file. When following steps on these online tutorials, I get to the stage where I need to sync the gradle project and I receive:

**ERROR: Could not find method bundle() for arguments [build_6plat2lh5rmq66u2k9bfvj0j1$_run_closure3$_closure12@655df9f] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.**

The steps I used to produce the issue:

### On Unity:

- I have set up a basic 3D animation
- Go to build settings

  - set texture compression: ETC2 > build system: Gradle > check: Export project
  - Set package name
- Click Export
- Select a folder for the library

### Android Studio

- File -> New -> Import Module -> Select project that was exported from Unity
- Project opens -> "Gradle settings are not configured for this project yet, would you like to use the Gradle Wrapper" -> Select "Ok"
- In `build.gradle`

  - Remove `applicationID` (as instructed by android docs)
  - Change `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
- Sync gradle project

### Where I found these steps:

- https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a and a couple of similar medium tutorials
- https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

### Version Info

- Gradle version: 4.10.1
- Android plugin version: 3.3.0
- Gradle wrapper properties distributionURL:
  https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

[EDIT] I forgot to mention that I removed [below] from the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same problem 
trying all things, commenting the bundle block fixed the problem for me

```
/*bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }*/
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach but after building the project and generating the apk I got my .aar file which I guess is what you are trying to get.

Comment: I had tried this before and wasn't able to access the methods of the library. But I thought I would give it another go since there are too many unsolved questions in life and maybe I did something wrong.
It worked!! Thank you, I must have done something wrong :)

Comment: I should add that project requirements changed and I am no longer using Unity so I have not tested it properly. Hopefully if anyone else has this issue, this will help them

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. To solve this, you need to change apply plugin: `'com.android.application'` to apply plugin: `'com.android.library'` and delete `applicationID` in both `build.gradle` as there are two.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle command can only be used in the project, commenting it is the correct way

```
/*bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = false
    }
    density {
        enableSplit = false
    }
    abi {
        enableSplit = true
    }
}*/
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the bundle {} part was outside of the android {} part. I placed it inside and it works nicely.

Edit: it wasn't Unity though, or a lib, just a pure Android app.